# How to copy directory into external driver in Ubuntu server 14.04?

Tags: linux, cron

Unlike desktop versions of Ubuntu, in Ubuntu server 14.04, I cannot do

```
cd /media/HDD
```

I have to create a directory and then mount width External drive to work with external drive or USB

```
$sudo fdisk -l
$sudo mount /dev/sdb1 `~/directory
```

But the problem here is external drive is not always the same. Sometimes it becomes /dev/sdc1, /dev/sdd1 and /dev/sde1 etc. So its unlikely to keep HDD as backup option.

I am keeping backup using...

```
$sudo vi /etc/crontab
```

Button line is, how to plug external HDD to ubuntu server and do backup without problem? For an example (which is not working).

```
cp -rv /var/www/backup /media/HDDname
```

Or any other solutions for my problems?

Answer (score 2):

You could easily create an entry in the fstab using the UUID or the Label of the hard drive partition instead of the assigned path.

You can get the UUID by running one of the following commands:

```
sudo blkid

ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

Then, depending on the partition type, you can add an entry to `/etc/fstab`, remember to change the line according to your UUID and `ext2` to your partition type:

```
UUID=30fcb748-ad1e-4228-af2f-951e8e7b56df /media/HDD ext2 defaults,nofail 0 2
```

Then, you could just mount all drives in the fstab:

```
sudo mount -a
```

Comment: Putting it into fstab looks like the cleanest approach